# dbt: could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I'm trying to connect dbt to BigQuery in vscode. For that I extracted a bigquery keyfile json that I put into the root directory of my dbt project.

I then created a profiles.yml file that looks as follows:

```
my-bigquery-db:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: bigquery
      method: service-account
      project: civil-parsec-350114
      dataset: dbt_dataset
      threads: 1
      keyfile: bigquery.json
```

Database Error
Runtime Error

```
dbt encountered an error while trying to read your profiles.yml file.

Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

When I put an empty projects.yml file I get the same error, so I'm not even sure if that file is loaded at all. How can I best debug this? What could be the problem?

Comment: I suspect your profiles.yml is not at the location where dbt expects it. By default, dbt expects the profiles.yml file to be located in the `~/.dbt/` directory. You could change that from the command line with `--profiles-dir SUB_PROFILES_DIR`. Additionally, I am not sure if you can reference the key file via relative paths (https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/get-started/getting-started-dbt-core#connect-to-bigquery).